# Помогите с простейшим алгоритмом передачи данных на java

Tags: java

Здравствуйте.
Есть метод, описывающий состояние передачи данных.

```
boolean downTimeFlag;
long dataBaudUpTime;
private void checkDataBaud(boolean isDataBaudRunning) {

    if (isDataBaudRunning == true) {

        downTimeFlag = true;
        System.out.println("Идет передача данных... ");

    } else {

        if (downTimeFlag) {
            dataBaudUpTime = 0;
        }
        downTimeFlag = false;            
        System.out.println("Передача данных не выполняется " + dataBaudUpTime + "сек");
    }
}
```

Вроде бы все хорошо и работает, но возникает ситуация, когда в параметр `isDataBaudRunning` передаются значение с промежутком времени большим, чем одна секунда.

Счетчик тикает и инкрементится на единицу, но по факту нужно считать секунды.

Вопрос в том, как правильно реализовать замер времени например через `System.currentTimeMillis()/1000` ?

Comment: а где Вы замеряете, где инкрементите?